# Dynamic inheritance based on variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have 2 chip driver classes, chip1 and chip2. Each of these chip classes inherits a reg_map class, which contains common methods to write and read data to/from the chip.

The reg_map class dynamically inherits a coms class which contains lower level protocol methods to talk to the chip. The coms class is inherited based on the coms_type variable declared at the top of the module.

```
from telnetcoms import coms as coms_t
from ftdicoms import coms as coms_f
coms_type=0 # switch between coms modules

def combo(chip_type):
    # This function is called by the test framework and returns a chip class 
    # based on chip type and coms type
    if chip_type in ['chip1']: return chip1()
    if chip_type in ['chip2']: return chip2()

class reg_map(coms_t if coms_type else coms_f):
    # reg_map is generic hardware coms class
    # coms_t and coms_f are low level hardware coms protocols
    # coms_t=I2C protocol, coms_f=telnet protocol

    def set_chip_register(self, reg_name, reg_value):
        print('reg_map')
        reg_num = self.extract_reg_info(reg_name)
        self.write_reg(reg_num, reg_value) # from coms class

    def read_chip_register(self, reg_name, reg_value):
        print('reg_map')
        reg_num = self.extract_reg_info(reg_name)
        self.read_reg(reg_num, reg_value) # from coms class

class chip1(reg_map):
    # driver class for chip type 1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dev_func(self):
        print('chip1')
        self.set_chip_register(reg_name, reg_value)

class chip2(reg_map):
    # driver class for chip type 2
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dev_func(self):
        print('chip2')
        self.set_chip_register('some_reg_name', reg_value)


myclass=combo('chip1')
myclass.set_chip_register('some_reg_name', 25)
```

While this does work, the combo function will be called from another module and I am looking for a way to pass in the coms_type variable.

Something like this:

myclass=combo('chip1', coms_type=0)

However I cannot see how this can be done using this structure, as the coms type variable has to be declared at the top of the script.

I know I could import a file and store the coms_type value in there, but I really want to avoid doing that.

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell exactly what the issue is because we don't have much context about what is the purpose of the different parts of your code, but it *seems* like you are trying to implement something that has the same purpose as the visitor pattern.

Comment: @BlackBeans, ok yes I take your point and have added some more detail in the edited version above.

Comment: If you'd be curious to inspect a Python 2.x codebase that did a bunch of very fancy metaprogramming (including changing the inheritance path for goal-seeking purposes), you may find https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/isg-state-machine-framework interesting. (Unfortunately, it's the open-source core of a now long-dead proprietary project, and the docs/examples/etc were all around the proprietary use and weren't able to be released -- so it may take some poking around to make heads or tails of it).